# Ti.cloudpush module not found

Tags: javascript, android, cloud, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

Hi I am implementing a push notification in my app using the ACS.I have added the Ti.cloud push in tiapp.xml which is as follows.

```
   <module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
```

and i am implemnting it using this code but it is giving error that Ti.cloudpush module not found.

```
var HomeWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#f00'
});
var CloudPush = require('ti.cloudpush');
CloudPush.debug = true;
CloudPush.enabled = true;
CloudPush.showTrayNotificationsWhenFocused = true;
CloudPush.focusAppOnPush = false;

var deviceToken;

var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
Cloud.debug = true;


var submit = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Register For Push Notification',
    color:'#000',
    height : 53,
    width : 200,
    top : 100,
});

HomeWin.add(submit);

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    CloudPush.retrieveDeviceToken({
       success: function deviceTokenSuccess(e) {
                    alert('Device Token: ' + e.deviceToken);
                    deviceToken = e.deviceToken
                    loginDefault();
                },
       error  : function deviceTokenError(e) {
                    alert('Failed to register for push! ' + e.error);
           }
    });
});


function loginDefault(e){
    //Create a Default User in Cloud Console, and login
    Cloud.Users.login({
        login: 'push123',
        password: 'push123'
    }, function (e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert("login success");
            defaultSubscribe();
        } else {
              alert('Error: ' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });
}

function defaultSubscribe(){
    Cloud.PushNotifications.subscribe({
            channel: 'alert',
            device_token: deviceToken,
            type: 'android'
    }, function (e){
            if (e.success) {
               alert('Subscribed for Push Notification!');
            } else{
                alert('Error:' +((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
            }
    });
}

CloudPush.addEventListener('callback', function (evt) {
    alert(evt);
    alert(evt.payload);
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickLaunchedApp', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running)');
    //alert('Tray Click Launched App (app was not running');
});

CloudPush.addEventListener('trayClickFocusedApp', function (evt) {
    Ti.API.info('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
    //alert('Tray Click Focused App (app was already running)');
});
```

Comment: What titanium version you're using?

Comment: Hi I am using the titanium sdk version 2.1.3

Comment: Hi none of the module is working on my titanium is there any problem with my updation because i have current version of 2.1.3

Comment: Wahhab, always keep your code clean so that others can easily read it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im also meet same problem even when i add

```
<module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
```

and i remove all project and create new project on titanium with deferment package name now it is working but i couldn't to find reason of my previous code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Wahhab,

Modify the tiapp.xml like follows and run your code. I had copied your code and it works well.

```
<modules>
        <module platform="commonjs" version="2.3.0">ti.cloud</module>
        <module platform="android" version="2.0.7">ti.cloudpush</module>
</modules>
```